# Reading Rows and Columns from File in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, io

I am trying to read this input txt file with my C code:

```
4 3
1.4 4.6 1
1.6 6.65 1
7.8 1.45 0
7 -2 2
```

and separate them into rows and columns so that I can sort. I tried doing that but I kept getting weird numbers.

So I tried printing out the rows and columns after I read them from the file and the output was zero. I realized then that my code is not reading the numbers from my text file properly. I have tried different means to fix to no avail. Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h> //for bool

int main(){

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL,_IONBF, 0);

int c;
FILE *file;
FILE *infile;
char filename[99];
char choice;
int rows, columns;


//while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
    printf("%s", "Enter file name: ");
    fgets(filename, 99, stdin);
    char *p = strchr(filename, '\n'); // p will point to the newline in filename
    if(p) *p = 0; 
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else{
        puts("FILE NOT FOUND");
    }

    //read rows and columns from file
    printf("%s","\n");
    fscanf(file, "%d", &rows);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &columns);

    printf("%d", rows);
    printf("%d", columns);
```

}

Comment: I'd use `fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin);` instead of harcoding the 99. If you later change your mind and change `filename` to `char filename[50];` and you forget to change the size in `fgets`, you could overflow the buffer.

Comment: @Pablo result is still 0

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1

```
int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
float matrix[rows][columns];
float sumOfRows[rows];
```

is not right.

After that, the number of elements in `matrix` and `sumOfRows` is fixed. They won't change if you change the values of `rows` and `columns` later in your program.

You need to read the values of `rows` and `columns` first before you define `matrix` and `sumOfRows`.

### Problem 2

```
    fscanf(file, "%d", &matrix[rows][columns]);

    printf("%f",matrix[rows][columns]);
```

are not right either. Given the defition of `matrix`, use of `matrix[rows][columns]` is not right. They access the array using out of bounds indices.
Remember that given an array of size `N`, the valid indices are `0` to `N-1`.

---

Here's one way to proceed to resolve your problems:

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &rows);     // Use %d, not %f
fscanf(file, "%d", &columns);  // Use %d, not %f

// Now define the arrays.
float matrix[rows][columns];
float sumOfRows[rows];

// Read the data of matrix
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
{
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j )
   {
      fscanf(file, "%f", &matrix[i][j]);  // Use %f, not %d
   }
}
```

Comment: did that the result is still 0

Comment: The OP's problem is in `while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (actually, two problems) are in the `if (file) {...` block. First, you use a loop to read all characters from the file. Because of that, at the end of the loop you are also at the end of the file. Any further calls to `fscanf` result in undefined behavior.

Second, if the file did not open, you print a message (to the wrong output) and still continue to the `fscanf` part, which *definitely* leads to undefined behavior.

Solution: Remove the `while` loop and fix the error handling code:

```
if(file) {
    // Nothing!
} else {
    perror(filename);
    return 1; // or return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it is reading the file now...however, when I try to output what row and column are after reading them from the file, I get row:0 column 3..it should be 4 rows and 5 columns. Any insight on why I might be having that issue?

Comment: In your example, it's 4 rows and 5 columns. Please include a _correct_ example.